# osx yosemite: mysql c & c++ connectorsL bad path?

Tags: c++, mysql, macos

This must be pilot error on my part but I am not seeing it. I am trying to port a linux c++ app to OSX.  I am using netbeans as the ide.  I have used both `clang` and `g++` with the same result.

The project is made up of two internal static libs, one of these has the mysql logic in it. There is also a shared object (`.so`) that is a plug-in for a third party tool and a command line interface to the `.so`.

On my development Mac I have the mysql connector libs for C & C++.  These were installed from the MySQL site: the C connector as a DMG and the C++ as a binary tar.  These get installed/moved into `/usr/local/` as:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 root  wheel  340 Nov 30 11:14 mysql-connector-c++-1.1.6-osx10.8-x86-64bit/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 Feb 25  2015 mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-osx10.8-x86_64/
```

It all compiles and links just fine.  When I run the command line tool -- which uses the `.so` I get the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
    Referenced from: /Users/me/myProject/myApp_Console/dist/Debug_OSX/CLang-MacOSX/./myApp
    Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I am specifically using the ***static*** versions of the mysql libs in the link lines.  a la (for the `.so`):

```
clang++ -O2 -Wall -fmessage-length=0    -o dist/Debug_OSX/CLang-MacOSX/myApp.so build/Debug_OSX/CLang-MacOSX/myApp.o -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.6-osx10.8-x86-64bit/lib -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-osx10.8-x86_64/lib -L../ITGUtilities/dist/Debug_OSX/CLang-MacOSX -L../UserTracking_LIB/dist/Debug_OSX/CLang-MacOSX -lpam -lpcre -lsqlite3 -lmyAppUtilities -lmyAppLib -lmysqlcppconn-static -lmysqlclient -stdlib=libstdc++ -dynamiclib -install_name pam_usertracking.so -fPIC
```

I have also specified the full paths to the static mysql libs instead of using the `-l` options with the exact same result.

There is no `/usr/local/mysql`.  I could create a sym link with that name but even then I want to build the command line util and the `.so` to be stand-alone so that I do not have to package up the mysql libs or force client machines to have equiv mysql libs installed.

I am not a Max developer so am I doing something wrong on the Mac?  Is Mac so different now that I am barking up the wrong tree?  Am I doing something silly that I can't see?

**EDIT**

I can make it work/run by creating a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-osx10.8-x86_64/  /usr/local/mysql
```

This doesn't feel right since I specifically set library paths before.

**EDIT 3**

Ah! light shines... I HAVE to specify full paths to the static libs I want to use.  I suppose the default behavior these days is to always use shared libs.  If I only use the `-l` versions then the build step ignores my desire for static and selects the shared version of whatever I specify.

Thanks for your time...

Comment: when i was new to mac c++ development, and even now, years later... linking and loading is always an adventure. if not today, then at some point you will need `otool -L` and `install_name_tool -id` and `install_name_tool -change`. if you don't know those yet, then learning them will come in handy.

Comment: the mysql-connector and the libmysqlclient are two separate things, yes? it is unclear to me whether you possess a static ".la" for the client or just for the connector.

Comment: There are two sets of mysql libs.  The connector c++ libs requires the connector C libmysqlclient lib.